# Como cerrar una aplicacion externa desde mi aplicacion

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment

Voy a simplificar la pregunta:

quiero lanzar en un momento una aplicación externa a la que desarrollé.

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.mariana");

startActivity(launchIntent);
```

y con este código abro la aplicación.

Mi pregunta es como ahora cierro esa aplicación que es externa a la que estoy desarrollando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una opción es implementando código en la aplicación para que al recibir un valor en el bundle, determine cerrar la aplicación.

Por ejemplo

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainOtraApp.class);
     intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
     intent.putExtra("cerrar_app", true);
     startActivity(intent);
```

al recibir el valor en el bundle que determina cerrar la aplicación

```
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("cerrar_app", false)) {
            finish(); //Cierra Activity.
 }
```